# Как выполнить cmd команду через C#?

Tags: c#, cmd

У меня есть кнопка, при нажатии на которую должен форматироваться диск, выбранный пользователем в списке. Реализовать это можно через cmd команду format, но как её выполнить? Ещё и с учётом того, что имя диска может изменяться.

Answer (score 4):

[Документация Microsoft - Process.Start()](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start)

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace StackOverflow001
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                Process.Start("notepad.exe");
            }
            catch (Win32Exception ex)
            {
               Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Вместо notepad.exe  format  с параметрами нужными.

Comment: Добавьте пожалуйста пояснение к вашему ответу.

Comment: Пример так пример.